# 64 bit hexadecimal to base 10 conversion

Tags: hex

The hex value is 1679EDDF2CFD1455

I am expecting the decimal equivalent to be
1.619587084 X 10 ^ 18

If possible, could someone please confirm this, and if possible I would love more significant digits to the decimal value.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not programming related!

Comment: using windows? plz use the calc application

Comment: Brainfuck implementation, anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using python:

```
>>> 0x1679EDDF2CFD1455
1619587083804677205
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt response. I also appreciate your time too. 
- S

Answer (score 3):

Windows calculator says it's 1,619,587,083,804,677,205

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt response.  I appreciate your time.
- S

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's what Ruby says:

```
jfpoole@brakhage:~$ irb
>> 0x1679EDDF2CFD1455
=> 1619587083804677205
```

Comment: This is lovely. I appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since everyone's doing it, I'll throw in the `bc` version. :P

```
$ bc
bc 1.06
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
ibase=16
1679EDDF2CFD1455
1619587083804677205
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm delighted that all four answers are the same.
:)

Comment: I'm delighted reading this... :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$ dc <<< '16i1679EDDF2CFD1455p'
1619587083804677205
$
```